# Centrifuge not using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, real-time, centrifuge

I just installed centrifuge (https://centrifuge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and created a configuration.json file and placed it in /var/www/ folder.

When I try to run centrifuge centrifuge `config = /var/www/configuration.json`, the server starts. However when I go to the default path `http://localhost:8000` in the admin panel it keeps saying DataStructure used as SQLite.

Here's my configuration.json file

```
{
    "password": "admin",
    "cookie_secret": "secret",
    "api_secret": "secret",
    "structure": {
        "storage": "centrifuge.structure.mongodb",
        "settings": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 27017,
            "name": "centrifuge",
            "pool_size": 10
        }
    },
    state: null
}
```

I checked and the MongoDB server is running on port `27017`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are starting Centrifuge using incorrect command line arguments. Try copy and paste into your terminal:

```
centrifuge --config=/var/www/configuration.json
```